# QML ListView filled by Javascript

Tags: javascript, listview, qml

I just realized that (according to some QML Bugreport) there is JSON Delegate for ListView missing. So I have two choices, fill it up by model created in Javascript or C++

Specially I need to download .json data from predefined URL and parse them to ListView.

I tried to create object array in Javascript and push assoc array to ListView as Model, but it failed. No matter how i modified the code.

So is there only C++ solution or I can make ListView model by Javascript?

Thanks

Code I tried:

```
return [{"name":"value"}]
return {"name":"value"}
return [["name","value"]]
```

The issue was always: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: name`

Comment: FYI: I did the same thing but not in javascript: https://code.google.com/p/qjsonpath/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Due to advice from mouli@irc.freenode.net#qt do this:

file: gui.qml

```
import "script.js" as Script

model: ListModel { id: list_model_id }
```

file: script.js

```
function makeList(id){
    id.append({"name":"value1"});
    id.append({"name":"value2"});
}
```

call:

```
Script.makeList(list_model_id)
```

Answer (score 9):

It may be a little late, but with Qt 5.5 (maybe earlier, but testet with 5.5) you can do the following:

Lets assume you have got an array like this:
`var dataArray = [{"name":"A"},{"name":"B"},{"name":"C"}]`

The code in QML to display this model:

```
ListView {
    model: dataArray //the array from above
    delegate: Label {
        text: dataArray[index].name
    }
}
```

The `index` will be provided for the delegate. It's the index for the current item inside the model. See [ListView delegate property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#delegate-prop) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

It's much easier to use [`Component.onCompleted`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#onCompleted-signal):

```
model: ListModel {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        append({"name": "A"});
        append({"name": "B"});
        append({"name": "C"});
    }
}
```