# List delegates driven live by JavaScript data model

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a QML application where I'm creating lists of elements received from JavaScript. Using the details from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31305304/405017) I'm populating the model as a JS array, and it works great. However, I'd like it so that when properties of the JavaScript objects change that ListView items driven from them update live.

Here's a simple test app showing the problem. The `ListView` is properly populated with `MyRow` instances showing the correct id/title, but when the `rand` property is changed by the timer, the List rows are unchanged (they show `0` for the last item).

[image]

**MyRow.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Rectangle {
    property var obj
    color:'#eeeeff'; height:20
    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill:parent
        Text { text:obj.id                           }
        Text { text:obj.title; Layout.fillWidth:true }
        Text { text:obj.rand                         }
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id:app; visible:true; width:200; height:100

    property var database: ({"17":"World","42":"Hello"})
    property var objById:  ({})

    function getObj(id){
        if (!objById[id]) objById[id] = { id:id, title:database[id], rand:0 };
        return objById[id];
    }

    ListView {
        id:mylist
        anchors.fill:parent
        model: [42,17] // object ids
        delegate: MyRow {
            width:parent.width
            obj:getObj(mylist.model[index])
        }
    }

    Timer { // Update every object's rand value every second
        interval:1000; running:true; repeat:true
        onTriggered: {
            Object.keys(objById).forEach(function(id){
                objById[id].rand = Math.random()*100<<0;
            })
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the delegate's `Text` items to update their text when properties of the objects change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (only?) way to get property bindings to work properly is to create real Qt objects to hook the values to. If you don't want to use a [`ListModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#listmodel) (because you want to quickly populate a model with items from a master library), then you can use [`createObject()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#createObject-method) to generate objects and pass them to your delegate.

Here's an updated `main.qml` that works as desired:

```qml
Window {
    // ...same as above...
    Component { // Creates real Qt objects with bindable properties
        id:objFactory
        QtObject {
            property int    id
            property string title
            property int    rand:0
        }
    }

    function getObj(id){
        if (!objById[id])
            objById[id] = objFactory.createObject( app, {id:id,title:database[id]} );
        return objById[id];
    }
    // ...same as above...
}
```

Additionally, you may wish to change the `property var obj` in `MyRow.qml` to a more specific `property QtObject obj` (or a more specific object type, depending on what you pass in).

Finally, note that it's slightly cleaner/simpler to use `modelData` instead of `mylist.model[index]`:

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill:parent
    model: [42,17] // object ids
    delegate: MyRow {
        width:parent.width
        obj:getObj(modelData)
    }
}
```